# django reloads variables every time a page is clicked

Tags: django, memory, global

I have a page that loads a list of tags for a search bar.  Every time you click it has to reload this list of tags.  How can I make it a global variable that is initialized when you visit the site and isn't reloaded every page click?

EDIT:  Better yet, how do I make it so the list is initialized and only checked once daily or weekly for updates?

Comment: You may use sessions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the low level cache api to do this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/. Once the cache is setup it should be as easy as doing the following:

```
   from django.core.cache import cache

   def view():
        search_tags = cache.get('search_tags')
        if not search_tags: # cache expired
            search_tags = get_searchtags() # substitute for your code
            cache.set('search_tags', search_tags, 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) # cache search tags for 7 days
       return view
```

This will mean that once every 7 days the search tags list is built and subsequent accesses are extremely quick.

Comment: You can also offload the building of the tags into another job so it isn't user facing if the time it takes to build them will negatively impact the user experience (even if it is once a week)